# bash: why the source command actually run the function? and how to avoid it?

Tags: bash

I have a function defined in my .bashrc file

```
function test(){
  echo "test function is run"
}
```

Whenever I try to source my .bashrc file to get some update I recently made, I noticed this function is actually ran and ran twice.

```
[myusername@myserver:~]$ source ~/.bashrc
test function is run
test function is run
```

This is annoying. 
I thought source command only load the function. 
Why it ever run it? 
and how to avoid it?
thanks.

Comment: Rename it `mytest` and your problems are probably entirely gone.

Comment: add `set -vx` at the top of `.bashrc`, and `set +vx` at the end of `.bashrc`, then run `source .bashrc`; objective is to see where in the script the prints are occurring; I'm guessing 'test' occurs elsewhere in `.bashrc` (or a subordinate script); **NOTE**: I don't get the printed output with a simple `.bashrc` file that consists solely of the function def, so there's gotta be something else later in your script that's generating the prints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you have existing code in your `.bashrc` (or invoked from your `.bashrc`) that calls `test`. That might sound strange — why is it already calling a function you've just created? — but it's because `test` is also the name of a command that's built into Bash [[link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)], and the existing code is trying to use that command. By overriding `test` with your function, you're tricking that later code into calling your function instead of the built-in command.

To fix this, rename your function to something other than `test`, so as not to interfere with that later code.

Comment: wow! thanks a lot. 
renamed the function, quit the shell and opened a new one.
Problem gone.
thanks a lot!

Comment: @BaozhenChen please accept this answer since it fixed your problem